# Rerun errored delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Some of the delayed jobs errored due to a bug.
I have fixed the bug and now I want to rerun the errored delayed jobs without losing them.
Is there any way to rerun all the errored jobs?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312054/manually-retry-job-in-delayed-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557555/delayed-job-how-to-force-processing-of-failed-jobs) may help you. Check out steakchasers comment.

Looks like the ticket is a two step process.

1. Query for the jobs that failed
2. Then update the `run_at` to `Time.now`